# Discord.py rewrite cog kick command not working anymore

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I'm making a bot in discord.py rewrite and started to use cogs I had a kick command that worked flawlessly now it does not work at all as soon as I turned it into a cog here is my code:

```
class Moderation(commands.Cog):
  
  @commands.command(name = "Kick", brief = "Kicks a Member from the Guild", help = ".Kick @User")
  async def kick(ctx, Member : discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    if ctx.message.author.guild_permissions.kick_members:
      await discord.Member.kick(reason=reason)
      em = discord.Embed(title = "**Moderation**", description = f"{Member} was banned because {reason}", colour = discord.Colours.red())
      await ctx.send(embed = em)
    else:
      em = discord.Embed(title = "Permissions Required!", description = f"{ctx.author.name} You do not have the required Permissions to use this command", color = discord.Colour.red())
      await ctx.send(embed=em)
```

and yes at the bottom I put bot.add_cog(Moderation(bot))

I get this error when I try and run it

```
Ignoring exception in command None:
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "kick" is not found
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you actually registering the cog? Also I see that you're missing `self`

Comment: do I need to add self somewhere?

Comment: In the function arguments? It's inside a class

Comment: I added it and it is still not working

Comment: You haven't answered my first question. Are you registering the cog?

Comment: I don't think so its in the same file as all my other code and at the bottom I just put bot.add_cog(Moderation(bot))

Comment: Did you put that after `bot.run`?

Comment: yes

def run():
  keep_alive.keep_alive()
  bot.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))       
  bot.add_cog(Music(bot))
  bot.add_cog(Moderation(bot))                                

if __name__ == "__main__":
  run()
`

Comment: You have to add it before, `bot.run` is blocking.

Comment: I just did still is not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232058/discussion-between-pynerd-and-lukasz-kwiecinski).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Moderation(commands.Cog):
  def __init__ (self, bot):
    self.bot = bot
```

Needed to add self.